# Cannot Sign apk file on cmd due to errors

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am trying to sign an .apk file created by Phonegap in a Windows 7 system.

Here is what I'm running:

> jarsigner -verbose -keystore C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\myCertificate.keystore C:\folder\myapp.apk myKey

Then I'm asked for the password and I enter it correctly. Lastly I get:

> jarsigner: unable to open jar file: C:\myapp.apk

I'm following the instructions from [here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-sign-apk-zip-files/)

Comment: There's a difference between the path of the APK in your command and the path in the message. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these instructions, and make sure you put filenames in quotes if they have spaces.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the apk is not located at the path you provided

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get jarsigner to sign my APK using Android's documentation or any workarounds posted in similar threads. Instead, I was able to sign my app using the `ant release` command using the instructions found here: [How to Sign and Publish a Phonegap App in the Google Play Store](http://www.adamwadeharris.com/sign-publish-phonegap-app-google-play-store-windows/).

In short:

1) Create a `ant.properties` file in `platforms/android` with your keystore information like this:

`key.store=/Users/username/Documents/path/to/my-release-key.keystore
key.alias=app_name`

2) Run these commands

`phonegap build android
cd platforms/android
ant release`