# How to solve "unable to open jar file" error when signing my cordova app in android?

Tags: android, cordova

I need to sign my cordova application in android. For this, I use the following command:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore C:\MyAndroid\Payment_New\platforms\android\\build\outputs\apk\payment.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk payment
```

Where *apk* and *keystore* are in the same folder.

After entering password, I get an error:

> unable to open jar file

How to solve this?

Comment: Are the answers on [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020523/cannot-sign-apk-file-on-cmd-due-to-errors) helpful?

Comment: @ShadowWizard i tried this but i have the same error unable to open jar file:android-release-unsigned.apk